# Hibernate database name change gives MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I used to have a database called `database` and everything was working well using hibernate and its models.

I removed `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">` to avoid update or create as it's a production server, we want to do it manually.

We recently switched to `database2` and so we switched the hibernate configuration file and all the hibernate XML models.

```
`<class name="com.api.models.database.MmApplications" table="mm_applications" catalog="database2">`
```

but it keeps looking for `database` event if we migrated the database, the models and the connexion.

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database.mm_applications' doesn't exist
```

Does someone can help me ?

UPDATE ----

Hibernate is connecting to the right database (database2), but there is a prefix as a prefix `database.` making the queries hitting the `database` instead of `database2`, and when I try to force the `default_schema` my queries become :

```
`... from database.database2.mm_applications ....`
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, It was an other application deployed on the same tomcat server using hibernate as well with another database (`database`) making a conflict with the new application ...

There is still something weird, by connecting to any database, hibernate will use the specified catalog in the hibernate models and so constructing the request using the catalog.table_name

Hope this help someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

My database is specified in the `hibernate.connection.url` property. Have you changed that also ? An example would be: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase`

Also, instead of removing `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` then perhaps you should set its value to `validate`. That way hibernate will ensure that the datamodel matches the database schema.

Comment: Yes I changed the URL in the config file for the new database name. I tried to use validate before and gave me trouble with text fields so I decided to remove it, I'm gonna try with it to see how it goes.

Comment: It's telling me my table is missing even, without using the 'database.' neither 'database2.' , but on my show tables it is here